# Spark-Scala maven build failing with ERROR : Could not access type DataType in value org.apache.spark.sql.types

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello fellow stackoverflowers, I have this Spark-Scala application that was earlier running on Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.4.4. I am trying to update the Scala version to 2.12 and Spark to 3.0.0. While I changed all the dependencies to Scala 2.12 compatible versions, the maven build is failing with the following error :

```
[ERROR] [Error] : missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Column.class'.
Could not access type DataType in value org.apache.spark.sql.types,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic 
classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'Column.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of 
org.apache.spark.sql.types.
```

Also the import statement `import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType` is unresolved in the IDE.
[image]

Here is my full POM.XML :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>cl.example.symphony</groupId>
<artifactId>fwk-sym-data-crypto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.12.0</scala.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.0.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <!-- <arg>-make:transitive</arg> -->
                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-logging_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>hadoop2-1.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>bigquery-connector</artifactId>
        <version>hadoop2-0.13.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalactic_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalamock</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalamock-scalatest-support_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.0</version>-->
<!--            <type>test-jar</type>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalacheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalacheck_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
        <artifactId>lift-json_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Can someone help me figure out the error? I looked into the latest Spark-Scala doc and it seems the class DataType is still available.